# Как сделать, чтобы заголовок пункта меню тулбара менялся после сворачивания меню?

Tags: android, kotlin

Кнопка list изменяет вид recyclerView и меняет свой заголовок на список/плитка. Но выглядит некрасиво, что сначала меняется заголовок, а уже потом сворачивается меню (Пример на скрине сначала заголовок изменится на "плитка", а потом свернется меню). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы обновленный заголовок показывался уже только при следующем нажатии на меню. Очень надеюсь, что понятно объяснила[image]

```
binding!!.tbNotes.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.list -> {
                    it.title = changeStateRecyclerView(isListView)
                    isListView = !isListView
                }
}
}

 private fun changeStateRecyclerView(isListView: Boolean): String {
        return if (isListView) {
            binding!!.rcList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
            resources.getString(R.string.list)
        } else {
            binding!!.rcList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 1)
            resources.getString(R.string.grid)
        }
    }
```

Comment: как вариант: использовать корутины и выставить задержку для переименования опции в меню. второй вариант, назначить слушателя на событие закрытия меню и в нем уже менять текст, только с проверкой, что кнопка была нажата. конкретная реализация зависит от вас.

Comment: Спасибо, идея с корутиной очень понравилась

Answer (score 0):

Если все это происходит во фрагменте, то можно использовать метод

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```